# Did the Norse goddesses fight during Ragnarok?

Tags: norse, ragnarok

Did the goddesses in Norse mythology fight during Ragnarok? Everything I have read is about the gods fighting.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, almost all we know about it is written in texts that were written after the viking age, so it is difficult to say that we have the full picture of what old norse people believed. No text mention the goddesses during *Ragnarǫk* , the only gods that are mentioned are Odin (*Óðinn*), who fights against Fenrir; Frey (*Freyr*), who fights against Surt (*Surtr*); Thor (*Þórr*), who fights against the Midgard Serpent (*Miðgarðsormr*); and (according to Snorri), Heimdall (*Heimdallr*), who fights against Loki. Snorri also says that Garm (*Garmr*) and Týr kill each other. And that's pretty much all we know about gods during the "God's fate".